# MySQL help/suggestions on optimizing a query on large database

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, query-optimization, large-data

I have a MyISAM mysql table with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `songs` (
  `rid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `song_title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `download_url` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `download_url` (`download_url`),
  KEY `song_title` (`song_title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `song_title_2` (`song_title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It has around 14 million rows. It's my first time handling such a large database and I haven't really cared about optimizations earlier. I've been trying out various things to test speed and accuracy.

**1) Full text**

```
select song_title from songs 
where match (song_title) againt ('search term') limit 0, 50
-- This gives me very unreliable results but speed is good.
```

**2) LIKE**

```
select song_title from songs 
where song_title LIKE '%search term%' limit 0, 50
-- Moderate matching results, speed is good when the query is 
-- easily able to fetch the first 50 results... but when i 
-- search for a term that does not exist then... here is the result..
-- MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 107.1371 sec )
```

**3) Multiple LIKE**

```
select song_title from songs 
where song_title like '%word_1%' and 
      song_title like '%word_2%' and 
      song_title like '%word_3%' and 
      song_title like '%word_N%' LIMIT 0, 50;
-- It takes about 0.2 seconds when the search terms are easily found.
-- Ran this exact above query just now to find the execution time when 
-- no results are found.
-- MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 30.8625 sec )
```

What I am looking for are tips and suggestions on optimizing the database / query regards to speed and accuracy.

I cannot use another search engine like sphinx since I do not have access outside the root of the site and cannot ask the guys handling the server to set it up.

Comment: P.S. Sorry about so many edits..
1st question over here and just learning how to indent code blocks.. but i cant seem to get it right after putting 4 spaces on the left of a line..

Comment: to indent code blocks - highlight and press ctrl+k

Comment: what is your serverside language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL cannot create index which will cover ***LIKE '%word%'*** query with leading percent sign because of the nature of B-tree index which used for that type of index. It will use index for prefix searches like ***LIKE 'word%'***. Please note, that LIKE queries are not covered by MySQL full text indexes at all. The only queries covered by MyISAM fulltext index are ***MATCH ... AGAINST ...***

Assuming your dataset size you do need an external search engine especially if you planning to increase amount of data you searching.

I don't have much details on your hosting environment, but if you have an SSH access to the hosting server I believe you can install and run Sphinx as non-privileged user. Set location prefix with ./configure script to your home directory (but please make sure it's not accessible from the web) like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/your/home
```

and then perform

```
make && make install
```

Then create sphinx config as described in http://astellar.com/2011/12/replacing-mysql-full-text-search-with-sphinx/ and finally start the daemon by running searchd from command line:

```
/path/to/your/home/bin/searchd
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A query using a like '%text%' does't use a index.
If you're looking for a good performance, use a full text version, even it not return exactly results.
If can use the command `explain select ...` to view what indexes are used in your query.

You can check more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: oh almost forgot about explain.. had read about it but never tried.. can learn something from looking at how queries actually work now.. ok..

Comment: just tried the like search and it does use the song_title index..
guessing you meant its not using the fulltext index song_title_2

Comment: @PrathameshGharat Can you provide `explain` results because `LIKE '%word%'` should not use index, it could be in `possible keys` column of `explain` but not in `key` col.

Comment: @piotrekkr: `SELECT song_title WHERE song_title LIKE '%word%'` uses index on `song_title` (index has all fields for the query - covering index, so mysql scans index because it faster than table scan). The index will also be used for `SELECT song_title FROM table1`.

Comment: @a1ex07 In manual for mysql 5.1 they wrote: The following SELECT statements do not use indexes: `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE '%Patrick%';` Don't know about 5.5 because couldn't find anything about indexes and `LIKE` in 5.5 manual.